# Usage of scrapyd instead of scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

Using  **scrapyd**  I can run  **scrapy** on multiple cores.

The following call i do using scrapy:

> scrapy crawl buch

According to the information there is no multiprocessor usage:

> Scrapy does not use multithreading and will not use more than one core. If your spider is CPU bound, the usual way to speed up is to use multiple separate scrapy processes, avoiding any bottlenecks with the python GIL.

This information is based on:
[CPU-intensive parsing with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744924/cpu-intensive-parsing-with-scrapy)

How can i now use Scrapy on all cores using scrapyd like in above example ?

Problem is there, that i cannot simply start it parallel and avoid then that the scrapers are all running the same list and crawling same stuff then parallely without splitting their lists of urls to crawl.

Comment: please reformulate your question, looks to me that you already answered yourself. About all spiders crawling the same list, you should think on a better way, splitting the list is a way, using limits another.