# Running multiple instances of a Scrapy Spider

Tags: scrapy

I have thousands of URL from the same domain (stored in MongoDB) that I need to crawl using scrapy. The thing is, the spider crawls the first URL, finishes and then picks up the second one. How can I make it pick up multiple URLs at once, all getting crawled in parallel - indepedently?

I can always run the command `scrapy crawl <spidername>` multiple times but I am looking for a solution more sophisticated than that.

Experimental Ideas welcomed!

Comment: Be careful - this sounds like a good way to get yourself banned from the domain you're crawling!

Comment: I understand the risks. Please assume that the domain owner has permanently whitelisted my IP address

Comment: @PraveshJain, have you tweaked [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) and [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain)? setting these to high enough value, scrapy should download lots of pages in parallel.

Comment: @paultrmbrth: Thank you for the suggestion.
I did not know of that setting. 
I see that the default value of CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN is 8. However, I am still seeing pages crawled synchronously.

Comment: there is no real parallelization inside a scrapy process: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21755434/858913

Comment: @eLRuLL: Thank you for pointing me to that link. Guess there is no real way to do that.

Comment: I faced similar issue and @PraveshJain solution helped me,
go to your setings.py file, find these 2 lines (they will be commented by default, un-comment them and increase them a bit, you shall see instant results

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the urls in Mongo in start_urls parameter of the Spider. Scrapy will then pick urls from this list and starts processing them concurrently.